# Where to find Z coordinate in G-code for Delta printer

Tags: slicing, slic3r, g-code, delta

I´m currently writing my own firmware for a custom Delta printer. Therefore I also need to read G-code from programs like Slic3r. Even with a small example like a cube, I´m struggling to find out where the Z-coordinate is hidden in the code. Here is a small example of the code.

```
; generated by Slic3r 1.2.9 on 2017-02-13 at 15:08:01

; external perimeters extrusion width = 0.50mm
; perimeters extrusion width = 0.58mm
; infill extrusion width = 0.58mm
; solid infill extrusion width = 0.58mm
; top infill extrusion width = 0.58mm

M107
M104 S205 ; set temperature
G28 ; home all axes
G1 Z5 F5000 ; lift nozzle

M109 S205 ; wait for temperature to be reached
G21 ; set units to millimeters
G90 ; use absolute coordinates
M82 ; use absolute distances for extrusion
G92 E0
G1 Z0.500 F7800.000
G1 E-2.00000 F2400.00000
G92 E0
G1 X-31.893 Y0.000 F7800.000
G1 E2.00000 F2400.00000
G1 X-31.893 Y-25.001 E3.57871 F1800.000
G1 X-31.496 Y-27.307 E3.72646
G1 X-30.350 Y-29.347 E3.87420
G1 X-28.588 Y-30.886 E4.02194
G1 X-26.413 Y-31.748 E4.16968
G1 X-25.000 Y-31.894 E4.25936
G1 X25.000 Y-31.894 E7.41663
G1 X27.306 Y-31.497 E7.56437
G1 X29.346 Y-30.351 E7.71211 F1800.000
G1 X30.885 Y-28.589 E7.85985
G1 X31.746 Y-26.414 E8.00759
G1 X31.893 Y-25.001 E8.09727
G1 X31.893 Y25.001 E11.25470
G1 X31.496 Y27.307 E11.40244
G1 X30.350 Y29.347 E11.55019
G1 X28.588 Y30.886 E11.69793
G1 X26.413 Y31.748 E11.84567
G1 X25.000 Y31.894 E11.93535
G1 X-25.000 Y31.894 E15.09262
G1 X-27.306 Y31.497 E15.24036
G1 X-29.346 Y30.351 E15.38810
G1 X-30.885 Y28.589 E15.53584
G1 X-31.746 Y26.414 E15.68358
G1 X-31.893 Y25.001 E15.77326
G1 X-31.893 Y0.075 E17.34724
G1 E15.34724 F2400.00000
G92 E0
G1 X-22.715 Y-22.716 F7800.000
G1 E2.00000 F2400.00000
G1 X22.715 Y-22.716 E4.86865 F1800.000
G1 X22.715 Y22.716 E7.73745
G1 X-22.715 Y22.716 E10.60609
G1 X-22.715 Y-22.641 E13.47016
G1 X-23.607 Y-23.609 F7800.000
G1 X23.607 Y-23.609 E16.45155 F1800.000
G1 X23.607 Y23.608 E19.43309
G1 X-23.607 Y23.608 E22.41447
G1 X-23.607 Y-23.534 E25.39128
G1 X-24.500 Y-24.501 F7800.000
G1 X24.500 Y-24.501 E28.48541 F1800.000
G1 X24.500 Y24.501 E31.57969
G1 X-24.500 Y24.501 E34.67382
G1 X-24.500 Y-24.426 E37.76336
```

Here are some configuration details:

- G-code flavor: RepRap
- Nozzle diameter: 0,5 mm
- Filament diameter: 3 mm
- Layer height: 0,4 mm
- Perimeters: 3
- Solid layers top: 3
- Solid layers bottom: 3

I will also provide the [full G-code](http://pastebin.com/YW05y3ze).

Answer (score 4):

It isn't hidden at all. It's just that the Z-axis position only changes with each layer change, so the Z coordinate is only passed at layer change. On line 19 of your example G-code, it starts the first layer at Z=0.5mm:

```
G1 Z0.500 F7800.000
```

The next time you should expect Z to appear is on the next layer.

Answer (score 3):

Your included code has a line which reads:

```
G1 Z0.500
```

I checked a couple of my G-code files for some of the past prints and I was able to identify the bed movement relative to the layer being printed. My slicer (Simplify3D) provides for the bed to drop during certain movements. I found `G1 Z0.600` followed by `G1 Z0.850` for one of the layers. When that layer was finished the `0.600` changed to `0.900` and the `0.850` changed to `1.150`.

This fit in with the model's layer height of 0.300 mm for that job.

I did not find more `G1 Zx.xxx` codes in your sample, but a larger file would contain those lines.